# FMIlibrary for PyFMI package(64 bit)

Tags: python-2.7, fmi

Anyone have idea to develop FMILibrary(64 bit) for PyFMI package.
FMILibrary(32 bit) compiled successfully with PyFMI package.
thanks for your useful ideas in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that needs to be done on the FMI library side to be able to compile it as 64bit. You need to grab the source from http://www.jmodelica.org/FMILibrary and use a C-compiler that supports 64bit then you are good to go.

Comment: I have to use source files but in the link which you have sent has files only related to win32. I tried by compiling it by source using FMILibrary-2.0.1-src.zip but I am not able to load an fmu using PyFMI-2.2

Comment: If I try to load an fmu I am getting error as FMUException: Error loading the binary. The FMU contains no binary for this platform.

Comment: Sounds like you are using a FMU not compiled for 64-bit. Try one of the CrossCheck FMUs that are in the Windows 64 folder on fmi-standard.org.

Comment: @jrhodin Thanks for your comment. I am able to load and use Crosscheck FMUs that are in windows 64 folder. The reason for my error is due to compiling 32 bit FMU.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem was encountered also [here](http://www.jmodelica.org/27858).

As for the FMILibrary, as far as I understand, it is nothing you have to compile with PyFMI. It is a prerequisite for the operation of PyFMI. What you need to do is compiling FMILibrary(check the required version for PyFMI from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyFMI)) using a compiler. And do not forget to show the path of FMILibrary to PyFMI.

What I would suggest, as in the first link stated, is installing Anaconda and working in a created environment.